# Visual Studio 2019 multiple monitors - windows switch screens

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I've got a laptop running 2 montitors. My typical set up is to have both monitors showing VS text editors (i.e. editing files on both screens) and things like solution explorer, test explorer, output, etc.. on the laptop screen.

The problem is with Visual Studio 2019 when I go from editing to debug sometimes the laptops window moves to the main monitor. Not always, maybe 1 out of 10 times.

Does anyone experience the same issue, and does anyone have suggestions on how to deal with it?

Comment: What position on the primary monitor does the window move to ?

Comment: Full screen ...